# Is there a standard notation for the set of negative integers and zero?

Tags: notation

There is $\mathbb Z^-$, $\mathbb Z^*$, $\mathbb Z^+$. There does not seem to be a notation for negative integers and zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrote $\Bbb Z_{\le 0}$, I’m quite sure that you’d be understood, and I have seen this notation.